# How to fix memory limit reached when downloading large files from FTP (using streams)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the error max memory limit reached in my Laravel application when downloading multiple large FTP files to my local machine.

Added streaming for avoiding the mem. limit error. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. What am I missing?

```php
foreach ($files as $fileName) {
 $path = storage_path() . '/app/files/';

 $disk = Storage::disk('ftp');
 $stream = $disk
           ->getDriver()
           ->readStream($fileName);

 \is_resource($stream) && \file_put_contents($path . $fileName, \stream_get_contents($stream), FILE_APPEND);

}
```

Comment: You should not load the full files into memory but only handle chunks and append them in a physical file on your server. That way the scripts memory footprint stays constant and small, regardless of how big the file is you want to transfer.

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ - that you are still reading the whole stream content in one go, so that it still completely lands in memory at that point. `stream_get_contents` reads the whole remaining rest - unless you use the maxlength and offset parameters to make it behave otherwise.

Comment: Ok, but how can I create this chunk approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can either edit your php.ini file

```
memory_limit = xxxM
```

Or through .htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit xxxM
```

Or in your script

```
ini_set('memory_limit','xxxM');
```